# Example of $\cap_{i\in I}\overset{\circ}{A_i}\subset \overset{\overset{\circ}{\frown}}{\cap_{i\in I}A_i}$

Tags: general-topology

I am struggling to come up with an example of $\cap_{i\in I}\overset{\circ}{A_i}\subset \overset{\overset{\circ}{\frown}}{\cap_{i\in I}A_i}$. I need to show a proper subset, and I want my index to be infinite. In the end, I know that I want to show $\emptyset\subset (a,b)$ or something along those lines.

The interior of $A$, denoted $\overset{\circ}{A}$, is $\overset{\circ}{A}=\bigcup_{\mathcal{O}\subset A}\mathcal{O}_\text{open}$. Some examples are $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{Z}}=\emptyset$, $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{Q}}=\emptyset$, and $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}$.

I have tried $A_i=\{x\}$, $A_i=[0,i],$ and $A_i=[0,\frac{1}{i}]$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your last example is very close. What if you try $[-1,1/i]$?

Comment: I tried this example. Here's what I did. Let $A_i=[-1,\frac{1}{i}]$. Then $\overset{\circ}{A_i}=(-1,\frac{1}{i})$, which implies $\cap_{i\in I}\overset{\circ}{A}=(-1,0].$

Note $\cap_{i\in I}A_i=(-1,0]$, which implies the interior of $\cap_{i\in I}A_i$ is $(-1,0)$.

Therefore inclusion is the wrong way. Right?

Comment: Ah, indeed, you have the containment wrong. The correct statement should be $$\text{int}(\bigcap A_i) \subset \bigcap \text{int}(A_i).$$ Note that, in fact, $\bigcap\text{int}(A_i)$ need not be open (as in our example).

Comment: I see what you mean Ted. But I am trying to show containment the other way. Is that not possible?

Comment: Nope, it's false!! As we've seen from our example and Olivier's as well. Part of the fun of such point-set topology exercises is deciding what's actually true by playing with examples and then proving it. :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I believe I am on the right track now then.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A_i=\left]1-\dfrac{1}{i},1+\dfrac{1}{i}\right[$ where $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $A_i$ is open we have $\overset{\circ}{A_i}=A_i$ hence
$$\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\overset{\circ}{A_i}=\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i=\{1\}$$
However the interior of $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i=\{1\}$ is clearly empty.

Comment: @jm.byrnes $\left] a , b \right[$ is "French notation" for the open interval commonly denoted $(a,b)$ in the rest of the world. Please do not make edits without a clear understanding of post in question.

Comment: @arjafi My apologies. I have never seen French notation before. You learn something everyday. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call $U$ the interior of $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$. Then $U\subseteq A_i$, for all $i$, hence $U\subseteq\mathring{A}_i$, for all $i$. Thus we always have
$$
U\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I}\mathring{A}_i
$$
If you also want the reverse inclusion, it cannot be proper.

Maybe you want an example where there is a proper inclusion
$$
\operatorname{Int}\Bigl(\,\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Bigr)\subset
\bigcap_{i\in I}\operatorname{Int}(A_i)
$$
where $\operatorname{Int}(B)=\mathring{B}$. (I find the operator notation is easier to manage than the one with the circle, there's no other deep reason.)